# Who is Hari? Is it the only entity named before OM?

Tags: vedas, name, vedic-chanting

We have 108 names of Vishnu which all starts with OM(AUM). But we call it Hari (and then) OM.

Comment: In Hare Krishna first word Hare can refer to Goddess Radha, just like in Sri Narayana first word Sri refers to Goddess Lakshmi.

Comment: Exactly where did he say it? I can only find one reference to Hari in the books you quote. Vivekananda writes "One of the names of the Lord in Sanskrit is Hari, and this means that He attracts all things to Himself."

Comment: Well, I think I remembered it incorrectly. It is Hari which is the only entity named before OM(AUM). We have 108 names of Vishnu which all starts with OM. But we call it Hare (and then) OM. Let me know if I need to change the question. Thanks Swami Vishwananda and brahma jijnasa.

Answer (score 3):

When we say "BhurbhuvasuvarOm iti digbandaha" during Puja/Japa for creating a protective circle around us, then also the (Vyahtri) portion "Bhurbhuvasuvar" comes before Om.

For example, from [this page](http://www.astrojyoti.com/srividya.htm):

> sauḥ – aiṁ – klīṁ –  hrīṁ – śrīṁ  astrāya phaṭ (open up the left palm
>   and strike it three times with index and middle fingers of the right
>   hand)
>
> **bhūrbhuvassuvarom**iti digbandhaḥ|  (using right hand thumb and middle
>   fingers and click clockwise around head)

So, HarihiOm is not the only such case.

Also, starting a recital with Harihiom is not a universal standard it may be practiced by only some Sampradayas. So, the practice is Sampradaya specific.

> Who is Hari?

It is another name for Lord Vishnu just like Hara is another name for Lord Shiva.

Comment: Is this the same OM(Aum) that we are talking about? Also, this is used in a sentence and not after any entity. I am concern if Hari the only entity.

Comment: No it is not the only entity.. that's what I have shown in the answer and yes it is the same OM only @karanpatel

Comment: Can you name the entity in your sentence? Also, a link which may have the entity brief detail.

Comment: In the answer itself I have given a link. Pls open it and see. The entity is the Vyahriti traya i.e **bhurbhuvasuvar** -- this portion also comes before OM. @karanpatel